# CardViews are all piled onto each other

Tags: android, user-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am trying to create an app that will have a list of cardviews. I have added three cardviews in markup like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="james_parsons.github.io.fblafashionapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This however, piles all of the `CardView`s on top of each other and makes them appear as only one:

[image: It only seem like there is one <code>CardView</code>]

I want my cards to be stacked vertically like the ones seen [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView). How can I achieve this?

Comment: @VicJordan When you edit, please refrain from [adding tags into the post title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), also make sure you are not creating new duplicate tags (your tag `android-material-design` was a dupe of `material-design`). Thank you for understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you case, `LinearLayout` suits you best. Also because the layout can be longer than one screen, you should wrap it with a `ScrollView`. Moreover, for `RelativeLayout`, the default position of child is top left, if you want something different, you have to specific some layout attributes, e.g. `android:layout_below`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="james_parsons.github.io.fblafashionapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

**Edit:**

Also, do not trust the layout preview totally, though it should be right this time. There are several limitations that makes the layout preview sometimes not accurate, you should only use at a quick test, and only trust the layout in real devices or emulators.